# Pool Manager Cannot load specified driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, ojdbc

I use I-net designer 16 with a Oracle 12.2 Database Source. In report Designer i have no problem to view the report results ('ve put ojdbc8.jar into the driver path of Clear Reports) but, when I try to launch that report on my web-application (deployed on Apache Tomcat) that give me this error:

[Pool Manager] Cannot load specified driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

; i've also copied the .jar file into the driver path on Clear-reports server.

Anyone have solved this problem?

Thanks